# QT with openCV GUI application lost functionality when run on different machine

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, deployment

I have a Qt 5.3.2 GUI project that uses openCV 2.4.8 compiled with MSVC110(x86) and packed with **InstallShield** into a single **setup.exe(including all the dependencies)**. I tested the setup on three different win7 machines and two of them ran the application beautifully **(No Qt or openCV environments are present on either of the three machines)**. On the 3rd machine I have an odd issue, while the application executes and the GUI is shown it has functionality losses, the major problem is one or more **slot functions work partially**(can't check if more than one function has a problem since I cant get passed the first one).

A simplified example would be:

A load video function not saving frames.
It starts with a prompt for the user to choose a video file using `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`, that part seems to work fine.

It then reads the video into `cv::VideoCapture vc(videoPath.toStdString())` I have no idea if this part works correctly.

Then it should save each frame in a **jpg** file using `cv::imwrite(path, frame)` but its **NOT**.

- **I get no Errors and the function just silently fails**

The code is NOT the issue since it works without any problems on two of the machines.

I'm truly lost, never seen anything like it before(I know there are some openCV functionality which can fail silently without a missing *.dll error but this does not seem to be the case since IT DOES RUN on two of the machines). So I'm thinking the issue is target machine related, **BUT WHAT CAN CAUSE IT?**

Just in case I wrote a small test function described above:

```
QString videoPath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select video file"), QString(), tr("Video (*.avi *.mp4)"));
cv::VideoCapture vc;
vc.open(videoPath.toStdString());
if(!vc.isOpened()){
    qDebug() << "Failed opening file";
    return;
}

int count = 1;
cv::Mat frame;
while(vc.read(frame)){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "test/" << count++ << ".jpg";
    cv::imwrite(ss.str(), frame);
    qDebug() << "wrote " << ss.str().c_str();
}
qDebug() << "done";
```

**Y does it fail?**

**PS: Its not writing permissions** ran as admin installed on different drives etc. without success.

**EDIT:**
Issue solved. It was with that silent failing of `openCV` I talked about in the question. Needed to distribute **opencv_flann248.dll** with the application. Hope it wont happen to anyone else. It's really a pain!

Comment: What is the different in hardware between the machines? This awfully looks like a driver issue.

Comment: @McKracken I't wasn't. the issue was with that silent failing of openCV I talked about in the question. Needed to distribute **opencv_flann248.dll** with the application. I still don't know how the hell it worked without it on the other machines though.